# Finding average rotation from an array of different points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

My name is Stanley and I need help :).
I am attempting to find the average rotation from an array of positions. (Stay with me here). If you are confused with what I mean, just like I am myself, then here is an example. I am making a boating game and there are raycast hits that find four points at each corner of the boat. In order to make the floating look realistic, I made it so that the average y position of all four points would be the y position of the boat. But the average rotation I cannot seem to figure out.

I have done some tests if there is a point at `0,0,0` and `1,1,0` and `0,1,1` the average rotation using xyz coordinates is `-25,-25,50` and I can't seem to figure out the math behind it. (I eyeballed the final rotation in unity and it looks pretty spot on, that is how I got that number.) If anyone has seen anything about this online like an equation or way of solving this it would be a huge help.

Thanks Everyone

Stan.

Comment: Surely this question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether I understood you correctly, but how exactly do u get an average rotation of (-25, -25, 50)? What I would do is (if the number of points are always three) create a plane, calculate the normal of that plane and trying to figure out what combination of rotation matrices lead to the corresponding components.

If your three points are (0,0,0), (1,1,0), (0,1,1) the corresponding plane's normal would be (-1, 1, -1),  and from that you could deduce what the rotations must be in order to get a reference vector (lets say (1,0,0)) that satisfies `R_X(a) * R_Y(b) * R_Z(c) * (1,0,0) = (-1, 1, -1)`

But I guess thats not what you want, do you?